# ZXingScannerView throws A method was called at an unexpected time caused by StopScanningAsync when navigating back

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, zxing

Using Xamarin Forms 3.6 with Prism, Fody and ZXing and running UWP app.

A navigation stack of `MainPage/Navigation Page/ViewA/ViewB/ViewC?selectedTab=Tab3.`

Tab3 has a ZXingScannerView control on it.
If I try to back button away to ViewB then the app crashes with the error 'A method was called at an unexpected time.'
The exception shows that it is trying to wait for the ZXing StopScanningAsync() method.

The page sequence is this:

MainPage which is a Master Detail showing View A initially.
View A -> View B -> View C which is a Tabbed Page
On the tab are 4 views defined as Content Pages, all navigable with Tab1 shown initially.
Tab1 is a simple data entry form
Tab2 has an input field, a button and an instance of CustomControl
Tab3 has a button,a ZXingScannerView control and an instance of CustomControl
Tab4 has a button, an Image and an instance of CustomControl

So when the user arrives at ViewC the navigation uri should be `MainPage/Navigation Page/ViewA/ViewB/ViewC?selectedTab=Tab1`

The problem is the back button action.
Using Prism Navigation I can trap the OnNavigatedFrom, OnNavigatingTo, OnNavigatedTo.
None of these events occur when moving between tabs.

There is a problem with the ZXingScannerView on Tab3.
I can click on each of the tabs and go forward and backward to show each page.
The back button (back to ViewB) works as long as I do NOT display Tab3 with the ZXing view. Scanning must be initiated by clicking the button so the control has IsScanning=false when the page is loaded.

If I tab to Tab3 (and any other tab before or after) and then try to back button away to ViewB then the app crashes with the error 'A method was called at an unexpected time.'
The exception shows that it is trying to wait for the ZXing StopScanningAsync() method.
The markup is this:

```
    <Grid
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    IsVisible="{Binding IsScanning}"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <zxing:ZXingScannerView
        x:Name="zxing"
        IsAnalyzing="{Binding IsAnalyzing}"
        IsScanning="{Binding IsScanning}"
        ScanResultCommand="{Binding OnScanResult}" />
    <zxing:ZXingDefaultOverlay
        BottomText="Place the red line over the barcode you'd like to scan."
        HeightRequest="20"
        TopText="Accepts EAN-8 or EAN-13 barcodes" />
    </Grid>
```

And the view model code is like this:

```
public Tab3PageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService,
                                         IEventAggregator eventAgregatorService,
                                         IPageDialogService dialogService
                                        )
            : base(navigationService, eventAgregatorService)
        {
            _DialogService = dialogService;

            this.IsScanning = false;
            this.IsAnalyzing = false;
        }

        public void Handle_BeginScan()
        {
            IsScanning = true;
            IsAnalyzing = true;
        }

        public void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                if (result != null)
                {
                    var payload = new PublishedEventPayload()
                    {
                        Code = result.Text,
                        ViewName = this.ViewName
                    };
                    this.AgregatorService.GetEvent<FindByBarcodeEvent>().Publish(payload);
                }
                else
                {
                    await _DialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Not found", "Unfortunately the ISBN code could not be resolved. Please try again.", "OK");
                }
            });
        }
```

On Tab3 I have put an OnNavigatedFrom event to ensure that IsScanning= false, but this made no difference.
The app would crash before it got to that.

Prism Navigation Service says that it will add new views to the stack when NavigateAsync() is called.
I have tried explicitly setting the full navigation path when going from ViewB to ViewC with no effect on the problem. The nav stack seems to be right when viewed.
It seems to be a navigation issue but I can't work out why the ZXing control is interferring.

Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help or not, but I've run into issues where ZXingScanningView does not respect setting `IsAnalyzing` and `IsScanning` when navigating. I was running into an issue that saw the camera continue to scan barcodes even after navigating from the page. It seems your view is also continuing to scan. My solution was to completely remove the ZXingScanningView in the `OnDisappearing` method then to re-add it in `OnAppearing` if needed.

Ex. I have my ZXScanningView housed in a grid that simply contains the ZXingScanningView and ZXingDefaultOverlay. When I set own my bindable property `ScanningEnabled` to `false` it will clear all children of the grid.

Comment: I will give that a try. Previously I had tried using the OnDisappearing method to turn off IsAnalyzing and IsScanning but that had no effect. Removing the control altogether might well do it.

Comment: Sadly this did not work for me. I encountered exactly the same error. 
My theory now is that it is to do with the platform version of the ZXingScanningView control. I am testing using UWP. The control currently comes from the *ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms* namespace and this is throwing the error. 

The Github project seems to include a fix for this for the UWP specific version of the view. This is in the *ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.WindowsUniversal* namespace.
 I am going to try to load that specifically and will see how it goes.

Comment: So far all my efforts have failed to fix or get around this problem.

I have put the creation of the ZXingScanningView in the OnAppearing event, and added it to the grid with the removal of the children of the grid into the OnDisappearing event. Still I get the fatal error 
This is without initiating scanning before hand.

I tried downgrading to version 2.3.2 of the control with no success.

Scanning actually works if I initiate that and navigation successfully goes to another page.
Fall back is to use a modal ZXingScanningPage which does work. Not very satisfactory tho.

Comment: I tried using ZXingScanningPage to do the scan and that works to find the barcode. Also tried doing it all in code as well as the xaml control. I can click back button and the navigation works properly.
Problem is that after scanning and returning through my result handling method the page now closes and goes right back to the root of the app, not to the calling page.
I think this might be becuase I am using Prism Navigation.
Sigh. Going to try downloading the repo and manually fixing there.